# running electron app with custom main.js file. Electron rather starts the default main.js file

Tags: typescript, electron, spectron

I have electron app with main.js which contains

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow(){
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
    console.log("loading file index1");
    win.loadFile('index1.html')
}
app.on('ready',createWindow);
```

and main2.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow(){
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 400})
    console.log("loading file index2");

    win.loadFile('index2.html');
}
app.on('ready',createWindow);
```

both main.js are almost identical and they should show different pages. I want to start the app default with main.js and provide an option to start the app with main2.js . in my package.json I have introduced

```
{
  "name": "mytestapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test:e2e": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/test.js",
    "main2": "npm run start ./main2.js",
    "debug": "./node_modules/.bin/electron ./main2.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.8",
    "mocha": "^3.5.3",
    "spectron": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "start": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

now when I start the app with `npm run main2` i still get the page index1 and the app dose not log anything
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `main2` script should be `electron ./main2` to do what you want.

`npm run start main2` won't start `main2`, because it runs `start` (`electron .`) script, which loads the default module electron finds. The default module is what you defined in `main` field

Comment: still the same please see the attached image

Comment: @test11 Have you tried to modify your `package.json` "main2" script to `"electron ./main2.js",` and then run it with `npm run main2`??

Comment: @test11 what I see from the image is that `main2` is loaded successfully. (that log is right). Why your `index2.html` is not loaded is an other issue.

Comment: "filePath should be a path to an HTML file relative to the root of your application" from [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsloadfilefilepath-options). Is it true in your case?